# First Pages only on Odd Pages with roman Page Numbers

Tags: header-footer, double-sided, scrreprt

I want to have the first pages (title, abstract, toc) of my bachelor thesis on right (odd) pages. The rest of the thesis should follow the twoside layout of scrreprt with arabic numbers.

I encountered a problem that the number 2 is on the left site cause of the twosite layout. Also in my approach the Links in the toc are not working correctly.

Please help me :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=14,BCOR=10mm,a4paper,twoside,parskip=half-,headsepline,footsepline,headinclude,abstracton,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc, headings=optiontoheadandtoc, draft=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{23,156,125}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}


\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark} 
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,amssymb}


\usepackage{csquotes}
%\addbibresource{literatur.bib}


\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}


   {  ~ \sffamily
  \vfill
  {\Huge\bfseries Titel}
  \bigskip

  {\Large
  Autor \\[2ex]
 Bachelor-Arbeit im Studiengang "`Studiengang"'
 \\[5ex]
   \today }
}
 \vfill

  ~ \hfill


\vspace*{-3cm}

  \newpage
  \cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{plain}
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \pagenumbering{roman}

{\bfseries\sffamily Autor} &  Vorname Name \\ 
            & Matrikelnummer \\
            & dauerhafte email-Adresse \\[5ex]
{\bfseries\sffamily Erstprüferin:} & Prof. Dr. Vorname Name \\
          & Abteilung Informatik, Fakultät IV \\
         & Hochschule Hannover \\
        & email-Adresse \\[5ex]
{\bfseries\sffamily Zweitprüfer:} &Prof. Dr. Vorname Name \\
          & Abteilung Informatik, Fakultät IV \\
         & Hochschule Hannover \\
        & email-Adresse
\end{tabular}
\vfill


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Selbständigkeitserklärung}
\begin{center} \sffamily\bfseries Selbständigkeitserklärung \end{center}
  % fett und zentriert in der minipage

  Hiermit erkläre ich, dass ich die eingereichte Bachelor-Arbeit
  selbständig und ohne fremde Hilfe verfasst, andere als die von mir angegebenen Quellen
  und Hilfsmittel nicht benutzt und die den benutzten Werken wörtlich oder
  inhaltlich entnommenen Stellen als solche kenntlich gemacht habe.
  \vspace*{7ex}

  Stadt, den \today \hfill Unterschrift
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Inhalt}{contents}

    \vspace*{7ex}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Gender-Erklärung}
\begin{center} \sffamily\bfseries Gender-Erklärung \end{center}

Aus Gründen der besseren Lesbarkeit wird in dieser Bachelorarbeit
 die Sprachform des generischen Maskulinums angewendet. Es wird an dieser Stelle darauf hingewiesen,
 dass die ausschließliche Verwendung der männlichen Form geschlechtsunabhängig verstanden werden soll.

%  \clearpage\clearpairofpagestyles
 \cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Zusammenfassung}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\section*{\abstractname}
\setcounter{page}{2}
Dies ist die Zusammenfassung auf Deutsch.
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage


\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{3}
\cleardoublepage

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your issue solved? How? Did you find environment `titlepage`? Why the different style (oneside) for titlepage until TOC, later style twoside? That is completly unusual! Use one or the other without change!